# how to change width of <th> without affecting <td> width

Tags: html, css

I have here 2 photos. 1 is my HTML page and the other one is my print page.
My question is, how am I going to make my print page the same as my html page? As you can see, the print page is less wide than the HTML page.

Also, I want to ask how am I going to make the width of `<th>` longer without affecting the width of `<td>`? Is that possible?

Sorry, I don't have that much knowledge in CSS.

**Print Page**
[image: this is the print page]

**HTML Page**
[image: this is the html page]

and here is my code:

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th align="left" width="20%">II. Documentation</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">Subject Routine</td>
        <td width="20%" align="center">Person-in-charge</td>
        <td width="15%" align="center">Complied</td>
        <td width="10%" align="center">Date</td>
        <td width="17%" align="center">Remarks</td>
        <td align="center">Signature</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1. Travel Documents</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2. National License</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3. NAC Certificates/MARINA COP</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4. Medical</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5. POEA / AMOSUP Contracts</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6. Flag License</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7. US Visa</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8. Joining Port Visa</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9. Other Certificate</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a nice print page width use media queries for example:

```
@media print {  
    @page {  
      margin: 30mm;
      size:297mm 210mm;  
    }  
}
```

Or use diffent stylesheets with different widths in stead of the same 100%

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link href="style_print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print">
```

And in the style.css add:
    `table {width:100%}`

And in style_print.css add:
    `table {width:297mm}`

Play with the widths untill you are happy in both ;)

Here are some great posts on how to set up CSS for printing: 
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/

Just add `colspan="6"` to your `th` to set the correct width of your first cell.

```html
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="6" align="left" width="20%">II. Documentation</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">Subject Routine</td>
        <td width="20%" align="center">Person-in-charge</td>
        <td width="15%" align="center">Complied</td>
        <td width="10%" align="center">Date</td>
        <td width="17%" align="center">Remarks</td>
        <td align="center">Signature</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1. Travel Documents</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2. National License</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3. NAC Certificates/MARINA COP</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4. Medical</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5. POEA / AMOSUP Contracts</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6. Flag License</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7. US Visa</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8. Joining Port Visa</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9. Other Certificate</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you. and oh, how can i set the properties when im printing it?

Comment: Added more in the answer

Comment: Added even more info, have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Tip: When I don't know what my html elements are doing I give them a border so I can see how they are behaving.  In this case you don't have the same amount of `<th>` cells as `<td>` cells - just add a colspan=6 ( the same number of cells you have ) and your `<th>` cell will span across the whole table:

```
<tr>
   <th colspan="6" align="left">II. Documentation</th>
</tr>
```

also you don't require the width unless you are trying to wrap the text ( but it sounds like you aren't. ) ...

oh, nevermind... answered above